# Returning JavaScript through PHP - good or bad idea?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

So I have a jQuery AJAX call that builds a profile when clicked. It would only be called once so I thought that I could just pop a script into the generated html instead of placing it inside the **success** AJAX call.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
      $content .= '
          <div class="content cols-1 points">
            <h3>Points</h3>
            <span>
              <b class="points_1" data-points="'.$row['p_1'].'"></b> 
              <b class="points_2" data-points="'.$row['p_2'].'"></b>
              <b class="points_3" data-points="'.$row['p_3'].'"></b>
              <b class="points_4" data-points="'.$row['p_4'].'"></b>
            </span>
          </div>
        ';
}

$content.= '
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(".points b").click(function(){
        setDots(this);
      })
    </script>
';

echo $content;
```

It feels cleaner, it only executes when I have the required html and I don't have as much JavaScript on page load... But is this bad practice?

Please explain any flaws if there is any. Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10142242/javascript-in-ajax-response Does it answer your question ?

Comment: So it is generally a bad idea... gotcha. However would it still be safe with code that only interacts with visual elements. Would it open up any security issues?

Comment: It's not a matter of security it's a matter of maintainability, to avoid rhetorical questions like "where the f*** did I put that callback function ?!!"...

Comment: Very true! I might forget about it if I want to change it later.

Comment: be aware that `mysql` is deprecated you should use `mysqli` or `pdo` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any particular flaws, besides the fact that the few lines of JS are returned with every AJAX response, which increases (very slightly) the size of the AJAX response, which in turn, given a lot of traffic, increases bandwith usage. That, and the fact that returning JS from AJAX is always frowned upon...

So I would write it in the page making the AJAX call using on event handler on document, like so:

```
$(document).on('click','.points b', function() { setDots(this) });
```

Comment: The traffic of this site will be very minimal (probably only 10 people at once) and this call is only made once. But it is always nice to learn good practices.